# Using properties and methods to dynamically access class variables

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have my own data types for use with a database that have various properties to manipulate values such as:

```
 First: original value
 IsNull: is the current state null (no value in Data)
 IsFirstNull: was the initial state of the object null
 Changed: has the value changed since the initial value was set.
 SetNull(): set the object to null
 SetFirstNull: set the initial value to null
 Reset: set values all to original settings.
```

Each one of the objects has these. There is an object for each type of standard variables, such as:

```
 int - IntType
 string - StringType
 bool - BoolType
```

I set up these types to handle the different states of each variable I read from a table as well as handle nulls. It was always hard to tell whether a value was null or not or whether it was null when the value was originally read so I would know how to write it back or whether the value was changed. Sometimes you need to know what the original value was when you read the data from the table.

So I only use these for data I have read from my tables, this is so I can keep track of values, including nulls, that I got originally and track changes as well as reset to original values.

I want to be able to access the data via properties, so I have it set up like:

```
 public class LoginDTO
    {
        public IntType loginID = new IntType();
        public StringType userName = new StringType();

        #region Properties

        public object LoginID
        {
            get
            {
                object value = null;
                return NullHandler.SetDbObjectValueFromValue(loginID, ref value);
            }
            set
            {
                NullHandler.GetValueFromDbObject(value, ref loginID);
            }
        }

        public object UserName
        {
            get
            {
                object value = null;
                return NullHandler.SetDbObjectValueFromValue(userName, ref value);
            }
            set
            {
                NullHandler.GetValueFromDbObject(value, ref userName);
            }
       }
```

To access the data, I could do something like

```
 loginDto.UserName
```

But to access (set or get) the IsNull property, I can't really use a property for each variable.

Normally, the access would be something like:

```
If( loginDto.IsNull)...

or 

loginDto.SetNull();
```

But in a class there can be many variables that come from the table a Person table could have 20 or 30 fields so 20 or 30 fields and 20 or 30 properties for these fields.

I was thinking about setting up a method in the class where I would pass the name of the variable, something like:

SetNull("loginDto") and somehow be able to set the method of the loginDto variable.

but not sure how I would access the variable to change the IsNull property of each variable.

How would I pass a literal ( i.e. SetNull("loginID") or SetNull("userName")) such that the method would know which variable to set?

Or is there a better way to do this?

I was thinking of scrapping the whole property idea and just set each variable and just access them directly since the propterties and methods are already set up in the DataType classes.  It was just that it is normally best to access your class variables from outside using properties.

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to write your own ORM. Is there a particular reason you've chosen to avoid pre-existing ORM solutions like Entity Framework or NHibernate? As for a call like `SetNull("loginID")`, that could be accomplished using reflection. But that's not going to be type-safe. Or even member safe. As in, what happens if somebody calls `SetNull("memberThatDoesntExist")`. And what if you need to rename a column?

Comment: Sort of.  But I just had the IntType, StringType, DateType as public which may be fine since they have their own properties.  But wanted to set up one SetNull for the whole class and pass the name of the property or object to it.  Changing the name isn’t a problem.  The problem I is I can't figure out how to set the property (i.e.loginID.SetNull()).  How would I do it using reflection?  Remember, this is done from inside the Dto class.